# Android/Java: how to avoid repetitive errors logs?

Tags: java, android, error-handling, kotlin

I've a **service** that runs every 5 seconds and fires 10-15 HTTP requests each time.

If the requests fail (timeout), I throw **up to 15 errors every 5 seconds**. That **bloats the log files**.

I'd like to **log repetitive errors only every 30 minutes**, even if the service runs every 5 seconds.

Any idea?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Why not using FIREBASE?

Comment: @intellij-amiya I like firebase, but it doesn't fit in that case. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Circuit Breaker Pattern](https://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/CircuitBreaker.html) for detecting long-term failures.

You still need a way to not log the errors during the long-term failure, e.g. by throwing a specific exception (LongTermFailure) in the Open or Half-Open state of the Breaker and treating that differently at your logging place.